# Do you have any suggestions on recording vocals/guitar using 2 mics?

Tags: microphone, recording, vocals, microphone-positioning, microphone-technique

i write simple songs with just an acoustic guitar and me singing. I have this [cheap large-diaphragm microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JRPYGE) and i am ready to buy this [mid-range small diaphragm microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006P3G5W8) to record the guitar.

But before i buy it i want to ask something. I want to experiment using 2 microphones (each at different gain etc..) to record vocals and guitar and i am not sure if this combination of microphones would work. Maybe for example use slightly the second mic at the chorus or something like that. What type of microphone would you suggest as my 2nd mic to experiment with recording using both at the same time but also to be used for simply recording acoustic guitar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "using both at the same time but also...for simply recording acoustic guitar" are you referring to stereo mic'ing techniques/using a room mic or do you plan to use the LDC for vocals and mic the guitar with the other? That's the impression I had at the beginning of your question. Is this multi-track recording in one shot or are you overdubbing?

Comment: Are you recording guitar and vocal concurrently?  Or are you "overdubbing" vocal AFTER you have recorded guitar?  Typically one microphone is used on the instrument, and the other microphone on the vocal.  If you are recording ONLY guitar, then sometimes one mic is used down closer to the bridge and the lower bout, and the other mic closer to hand for higher-frequency transient sounds, etc.  But half the fun is experimenting with different mic placement to see what works for YOUR instrument and playing, and what YOU like to hear.

Answer (score 1):

As aeroNotAuto mentions in his comment more information on how you are planning on experimenting (mic placement, recording techniques & equipment, etc) would be helpful.

Mic choice boils down to how a mic sounds ***to you*** in the situation you place it. So your choice for your second mic would work fine since there's really no "wrong" answer. That being said, I'm not sure you wouldn't be better served upgrading your LD mic since getting a mic that offers different polar pattern choices expands what/how you can experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I would buy another MXL V67G so you can have a balanced stereo recording of the guitar (one mic pointing to the bridge and the other one somewhere between the soundhole and the 12th fret). That mic should be well suited for vocals too.

The interesting setup would be when you want to record the guitar and sing at the same time, in which I would use an XY config of the mics, so your voice would sit right in the middle while the guitar has a stereo spread.